# Iterating through columns and storing values of different columns simultaneous

Tags: python, pandas

Iterating through 4 columns and extracting values, when columns quantity bought and Buy price(342,21) is filled it should be extracted then the next row should be checked where again it will fetch Quantity bought and buy price(2330,45), but then while checking the next row which is nan i want to extract sell quantity and sell price(110,56)

```
I Have the below Dataframe 
I wanted to extract values of 4 columns row by row
Quantity bought=342,21
Date=20.3.2019
Quantity Bought=2330,45
Date=21.3.2019
then it will fetch the other columns value
Quantity Sold=110,56
Date=22.3.2019
then again extracted are 
Quantity Sold=221,21
Date=24.3.2019
then 
Quantity Bought=344,22
Date=25.5.2019
then 
Quantity Sold=455,29
29.6.2019 
Quantity Sold=566,30
Date=30.6.2019


ef={'Date':['20.3.2019','21.3.2019','22.3.2019','24.3.2019','25.5.2019','29.6.2019','30.6.2019'],
    'Quantity Bought':[342.0,2330.0,'nan','nan',344,'nan','nan'],
    'Buy Price':[21.0,45.0,'nan','nan',22,'nan','nan'],
    'Sell Quantity':['nan','nan',110,221,'nan',455,566],
    'Sell Price':['nan','nan',56,21,'nan',29,30]}
ef=pd.DataFrame(ef)


#And I wanted to be  added simultaneously in

el=[Trade(pd.to_datetime('20.03.2019',format='%d.%m.%Y'), 342, 21)]                                                                       
el = [Trade(pd.to_datetime('21.03.2019',format='%d.%m.%Y'), 2330, 45)
el.append(Trade(pd.to_datetime('22.03.2016',format='%d.%m.%Y'), -110, 56))
el.append(Trade(pd.to_datetime('24.03.2016',format='%d.%m.%Y'), -221, 21))
el.append(Trade(pd.to_datetime('25.05.2016',format='%d.%m.%Y'), 344, 22)) 
el.append(Trade(pd.to_datetime('29.06.2016',format='%d.%m.%Y'), -455, 29))
el.append(Trade(pd.to_datetime('30.06.2016',format='%d.%m.%Y'), -566, 30))]
```

Comment: Don't paste pictures. Paste the data as text. It is not clear what you are looking for. So, please include the expected out put in your question as well.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you mean:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


ef={'Date':['20.3.2019','21.3.2019','22.3.2019','24.3.2019','25.5.2019','29.6.2019','30.6.2019'],
    'Quantity Bought':[342.0,2330.0,'nan','nan',344,'nan','nan'],
    'Buy Price':[21.0,45.0,'nan','nan',22,'nan','nan'],
    'Sell Quantity':['nan','nan',110,221,'nan',455,566],
    'Sell Price':['nan','nan',56,21,'nan',29,30]}
ef=pd.DataFrame(ef)

ef.replace('nan', np.nan, inplace=True)

numberOfRows = len(ef.index)

el={'Date':[],
    'Quantity':[],
    'Price':[]}
el = pd.DataFrame(el)

row = 0
i = 0

while i < numberOfRows:
    if ef.isnull().iat[row,1] != True:
        adding = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[ef.iat[row,0]],
                               "Quantity":[ef.iat[row,1]],
                               "Price":[ef.iat[row,2]]})
        el = el.append(adding, ignore_index=True)
        i += 1
        row += 1
    else:
        adding = pd.DataFrame({"Date": [ef.iat[row, 0]],
                               "Quantity": [ef.iat[row, 3]*(-1)],
                               "Price": [ef.iat[row, 4]]})
        el = el.append(adding, ignore_index=True)
        i += 1
        row += 1
print(el)
```

Comment: Yes it is right, but I wanted to these values to this line `el=[Trade(pd.to_datetime('20.03.2019', format='%d.%m.%Y'), 342, 21)]` one by one,so its like whenever the dataframe gets modified or any values come into the dataframe it should be automatically added to this line